# camera2 burst capture manual mode

Tags: android, capture, android-camera2

I use burst capture based on camera2, set Iso and exposure time value. Set ISO 50, EXPOSURE TIME 1/30s, but some pictures would turn to ISO 100, Exposure time 1/60.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten the pictures with my setting value, reference:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/a0077cc/tests/tests/hardware/src/android/hardware/camera2/cts/BurstCaptureRawTest.java

- Construct an array of burst request with manual exposure and sensitivity.

  - 
  - For each capture request, 3A and post processing (noise reduction, sharpening, etc) will be
  - turned off. Then exposure and sensitivity value will be configured, which are determined by
  - EXPOSURE_MULIPLIERS and SENSITIVITY_MULTIPLIERS.
  - *
  - @param rawBurstBuilder The builder needs to have targets setup.
  - @return An array list capture request for burst.
    */
    private ArrayList createBurstRequest(CaptureRequest.Builder rawBurstBuilder)
    {
    return createBurstRequest(rawBurstBuilder, EXPOSURE_MULTIPLIERS, SENSITIVITY_MLTIPLIERS);
    }
    private ArrayList createBurstRequest(CaptureRequest.Builder rawBurstBuilder,
        long[] exposureMultipliers, int[] sensitivityMultipliers) {
    // set manual mode
    rawBurstBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
    rawBurstBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_OFF);
    rawBurstBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE,
            CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_OFF);
    rawBurstBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_OFF);
    // exposure has higher priority over frame duration; therefore the frame readout time:
    // exposure time + overhead
    rawBurstBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION, 0L);
    // get the exposure and sensitivity range
    Range exposureRangeNs = new Range(mStaticInfo.getExposureMinimumOrDefault(),
            mStaticInfo.getExposureMaximumOrDefault());
    Range isoRange = new Range(mStaticInfo.getSensitivityMinimumOrDefault(),
            mStaticInfo.getSensitivityMaximumOrDefault());
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Exposure time - max: %d, min: %d.", exposureRangeNs.getUpper(),
            exposureRangeNs.getLower()));
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Sensitivity - max: %d, min: %d.", isoRange.getUpper(),
            isoRange.getLower()));
    // building burst request
    int maxFramesBurst = exposureMultipliers.length * sensitivityMultipliers.length;
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Setting up burst = %d frames.", maxFramesBurst));
    ArrayList rawRequestList = new ArrayList(maxFramesBurst);
    for (int i = 0; i < exposureMultipliers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sensitivityMultipliers.length; j++) {
            long desiredExposure = Math.min(
                    exposureRangeNs.getLower() * exposureMultipliers[i],
                    exposureRangeNs.getUpper());
            int desiredSensitivity =
                    Math.min(isoRange.getLower() * sensitivityMultipliers[j],
                            isoRange.getUpper());
            rawBurstBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, desiredExposure);
            rawBurstBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, desiredSensitivity);
            rawRequestList.add(rawBurstBuilder.build());
        }
    }
    return rawRequestList;
    }